# Multiple classes assigned via D3's .attr are not in the serialized (serializeToString) string

Tags: javascript, serialization, svg, d3.js

When attempting to serialize the SVG elements created by D3, multiple classes are not appearing in the resulting string. For example,  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318 has a bit that adds a class to indicate the color of the data point:

```
  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
```

It renders properly in the browser, and when inspecting the element they look like this:

```
  <rect class="day q7-11" ...
```

Yet when I serialize the elements, they are like this (i.e. missing the second class):

```
  <rect class="day" ...
```

I am serializing the code by placing the following at the bottom of the code linked to above:

```
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  var str = serializer.serializeToString(svg[3]);
  console.log(str);
```

As broader context, I have a process that batch produces D3 graphs by sending serialized SVG to the server for conversion to images. The process works except for this one bug.

So I am looking for a way to serialize this second class as well as the first without having to modify my process too much.

Comment: Does it make a difference –– and still render properly –– if instead of `.attr("class", ...)` you use `.property("class", ...)`

Comment: The following works in Chrome and Firefox, for HTML and SVG nodes: http://jsfiddle.net/Fjuy5/1/

Answer (score 0):

The code applying the second class is within d3.csv(), which is asynchronous. So the serialization is occurring prior to the class update. Placing the serialization code within the d3.csv() callback fixes the issue.